# Need help solving the following summation

Tags: summation

I need help solving the following summation:

$$2^{x-1}\sum_{y=x}^{\infty} \frac y{2^y} $$

for $y\ge x\ge 1$

I tried writing out terms to solve but that did not go anywhere. I'm not sure what else I should try or if this fits a certain summation type (i.e. geometric).

Comment: Consider $\sum_{y=x}^{\infty} s^y$, find a simplified expression for the series, write the equality for the series, and differentiate with respect to $s$ on both sides of the equality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2^{x-1}\sum_{y=x}^\infty\frac{y}{2^y}}&=2^{x-2}\sum_{y=x}^\infty y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=2^{x-2}\sum_{y=x}^\infty\left.\left(\frac{d}{dt}t^y\right)\right|_{t=1/2}\tag{2}\\
> &=2^{x-2}\left.\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{y=x}^\infty t^y\right)\right|_{t=1/2}\tag{3}\\
> &=2^{x-2}\left.\left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{t^x}{1-t}\right)\right]\right|_{t=1/2}\tag{4}\\
> &=2^{x-2}\cdot\left.\frac{t^{x-1}(-tx+t+x)}{(1-t)^2}\right|_{t=1/2}\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=x+1}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we do a rearrangement and prepare for introducing differentiation.
- In (2) we write the expression with the help of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ evaluated at $t=\frac{1}{2}$.
- In (3) we exchange series and differential operator which is valid for $|t|<1$.
- In (4) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)*.
- In (5) we do the differentiation.
- In (6) we evaluate at $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^n = \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}.\tag1$$
There are various ways to prove this, including the use of a differential as in
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2274660/139123).
See [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/).
This is a variation on the even better-known sum of a geometric series,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac1{1-r}.$$
Notice that if we start this last sum from $n=1$ instead of $n=0,$ we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n = r\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n =\frac{r}{1-r}.\tag2$$

In the question, the index of the summation starts from $x,$ not from $1.$
We can address this in either of two ways: generalize $(1)$ so that the index can start from any integer, or change the indexing in the summation in the question. Let's change the indexing by making the substitution
$y = u + x - 1.$ Then $u=1$ when $y=x,$ and

\begin{align}
2^{x-1}\sum_{y=x}^{\infty} \frac y{2^y} 
&= 2^{x-1}\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac{u+x-1}{2^{u+x-1}} \\
&= 2^{x-1}\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac1{2^{x-1}}\frac{u+x-1}{2^u}\right)\\
&= \sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac{u+x-1}{2^u}\\
&= \sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac{u}{2^u} + (x-1)\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^u}\\
&= \frac{\left(\frac12\right)}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2}
   + (x-1)\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^u}
   & \text{application of $(1)$} \\
&= 2 + (x-1)\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^u} \\
&= 2 + (x-1)\frac{\left(\frac12\right)}{1-\frac12}
   & \text{application of $(2)$} \\
&= 2 + (x-1) \\
&= x + 1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If expanded:

$$2^{x-1}\sum_{y=x}^{\infty} \frac y{2^y}=2^{x-1}\left(\frac{x}{2^x}+\frac{x+1}{2^{x+1}}+\frac{x+2}{2^{x+2}}+\cdots\right)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x+1}{2^2}+\frac{x+2}{2^3}+\cdots=$$
$$x\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots}_{=1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{2}{2^3}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\cdots\right)=$$
$$x+\left([\underbrace{\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\cdots}_{=\frac{1}{2}}]+\underbrace{[\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\cdots}_{\frac{1}{2^2}}]+\underbrace{[\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\cdots}_\frac{1}{2^3}]+\cdots\right)=$$
$$x+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots\right)=x+1.$$